# how to remove this faucet aerator? it just slips

Tags: faucet

I have the following type of faucet aerator:

[image: faucet aerator]
[image: under]

I tried to "unscrew" this one, but it seems not screwed at all; it just spins. Is there any way to remove this? As it is a separate part, there must be a way to remove it. Please help.

Comment: When you say "it just slips", do you mean that it just spins, or that you can't get a grip on it and your tool is slipping?

Comment: @Steven it just spins. grip is not a problem, yet.

Comment: Have you tried pulling down? I'm wondering if maybe there is an outer ring

Comment: From the second photo, it looks like you need a special tool to go in those notches on either side of the aerator, unless those notches spin freely too.

Comment: Bmitch is right.  You need a spanner wrench or some narrow pointed needle nose pliers to get into those notches.

Answer (score 7):

A bit late, but for anyone still wondering I had this problem today. I took two forks and put one prong on each into those little notches and turned counter clockwise until I felt it becoming loose. At that point, I just had to unscrew it a bit more and it came off.

Answer (score 3):

You need a DANCO key or a pair of forks.

[image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming!

Answer (score 1):

Wrap a rag around it and grab it with a pair of pliers. The rag will protect the finish. If you can't get a good enough grip on it, just use the pliers then buy a new aerator. If you mean that it keeps turning in the thread, then the threads are stripped and it's time for a new faucet.

Comment: this one has an internal threaded cartridge, outside spins.